# Code completion / intellisense options

Tags: code-completion

So I've been using Visual Studio for years and I've grown fully accustomed to Intellisense. At my new job, however, I've been using Xcode and it does a few things that Intellisense doesn't.

For example, Xcode expands macros before checking, so (ok I'm only using a singleton for demonstrative purposes here)

```
#define INST class::getInstance()

INST->method();
```

`method()` will be detected properly by Xcode but not by VS.

All this has been a lead-up to: what is the best code-completion tool out there? What program does it run on (VS, Emacs, Eclipse...)? What makes it so handy? And, if it's a plugin, where does one get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best C++ code completion I've seen is what comes with [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/), which is a plugin for Visual Studio (unfortunately not free).  I've tried some other, similar VS plugins, but none quite measured up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to go with Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2. *That* is some impressive C++ IntelliSense.